# Android listview scrollable when there are not enough elements to fit view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll, listitem

i know ListView scrolling is dynamical, so basically i cannot scroll when there are just few elements what are not filling the view of listview.
But is there some possibility to make it scrollable?

I have something like:

-- listview 
----- Search listItem 
----- item_1 
----- item_2 
----- ...... 
----- item_n

The search listItem is always 'hidden' (its not really hidden, the listview just show items by setSelection(1), so the search listItem is reachable but at start its not shown)..
Problem is, when i got just few elements like for example 1-4. Those elements will not fit the view and setSeleciton(1) does not work and it shown up the search listItem as well..
Is there any possibility to make it 'hidden' (not visible in screen, because it will be above the first visible item) and show it by scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the height of your Search listItem view and then use that in `scrollBY(0,height)`. Not elegant but i think it will suffice.